# Nonrepeating gradient that fits the whole page

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to make a background for the website I'm designing that is a gradient all the way to the bottom of the page but currently it repeats every time it gets to the bottom of my screen. I'm using the code:

```
html {
    height: 2520;
}
body {
    height: 2500px;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, white, #a6f2c0 30%, rgba(180, 200, 210, .9), black);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, white, #a6f2c0 30%, rgba(180, 200, 210, .9), black);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, white, #a6f2c0 30%, rgba(180, 200, 210, .9), black);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, from(white), color-stop(0.3, #a6f2c0), color-stop(0.65, rgba(180, 200, 210, .9)), to(black));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, white, #a6f2c0 30%, rgba(180, 200, 210, .9), black);
    background: linear-gradient(top left, white, #a6f2c0 30%, rgba(180, 200, 210, .9), black);
    }
```

and I'm wondering if making a gradient never repeat is impossible. Please let me know if it can be done and if so how it can be done. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `-ms-linear-gradient` never existed, IE10 supports the unprefixed version... provided you use the correct `to bottom` direction instead of `top left`

Comment: So you mean use: background: -linear-gradient(to bottom, white, #a6f2c0 30%, rgba(180, 200, 210, .9), black);

Comment: I think that the -ms- works with a filter you put in the head... see http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had no px on your html size. But you should do it like this. [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ncdN8/)

HTML

```
<html><body>
    <div class="main-content-wrapper">

        ALL OF YOUR CONTENT

    </div>
</body></html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-content-wrapper {
    min-height: 2520px; /* remove this. let the content decide this height */
    background: #ea2e9c;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ea2e9c 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ea2e9c), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ea2e9c 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ea2e9c 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ea2e9c 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ea2e9c 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ea2e9c', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 );
e background-image(linear-gradient(top,  #ea2e9c 0%,#7db9e8 100%));
}
```

Comment: Making your html { height: 4561; } doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: The problem is that the gradient you made and all of the different gradients I have tried repeat because they only last 100% of the screen height instead of 100% of the web page. I did html {
    height: 2520;
} because all of my pages are the same height and I was trying to stretch the background to the length of the page.

Comment: well... what if the page is less wide? does the text stack up and change the height? Some thing to think about. You need some unit on that height. 2520 doesn't mean anything. I have an idea for you though...

Comment: @Austin : I've updated the answer and fiddle - this should be what you are looking for, and I think more future friendly as well. Good luck! You got me kinda excited to so something similar width this. If you make the gradient with 10 colors, it will have tons of color changes. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/